# Installing older version Google Plugin for Eclipse

Tags: android, google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin

How to install older version of Google Plugin for Eclipse (2.6). When using software install in eclipse, only the latest version of the plugin is available.

I need to install the previous version because of some functionalities were removed in latest version of GPE, specifically the android connected app engine project.

Thanks.

Comment: This: https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/appeng_android_install_setup doesn't work?

Comment: This will install the latest version of GPE with the functionality removed.

Comment: Which functionality are you looking for? As there appears to be Android client wizard which uses C2DM. https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/appengine_connected_android

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the sdk downloading page, marking the box to "All"? http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/downloads/list?can=1&q=&colspec=Filename+Summary+Uploaded+ReleaseDate+Size+DownloadCount

Comment: this is not the one im looking, the Google Plugin for Eclipse